# NSInteger release

Tags: iphone, release, nsinteger

```
DetailViewController.h   

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    NSInteger getInteger;
    NSNumber *getNumber;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *getNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger getInteger => Doesn't work with warning.
```

I know that NSNumber is able to release. So, I add code like this:

```
DetailViewController.m
@synthesize getNumber;
...
...
- dealloc{
  [getNumber release];
}
```

But how to release NSInteger? Doesn't it require release? I don't know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSInteger` is equivalent to `int` (on iPhone). It is not an ObjC object. You won't and can't `-retain` or `-release` them.

Answer (score 2):

NO ALLOC = NO DEALLOC.